# jQgrids loadComplete is not firing in IE7

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, internet-explorer-7

Using jqgrid in one of my web applications I found its not working in IE7 only. On other browser its working fine IE8+, chrome, FF.

While debugging I found that loadComplete() method is not firing in IE7 although its firing in other browsers.

Using fiddler I found that I am getting correct json and response but why loadComplete is not firing? how to investigate this problem?

```
        loadComplete : function(){
            alert('lc');

        },
```

Comment: Sorry, but the callback `loadComplete` do called in all web browsers in generally. If you have a test case where it will be not done you should post the demo which can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you want to investigate the problem yourself I would recommend you to start the code in Developer Tools of IE (press F12 to start) and then starting debugging in the Script tab. I suppose you get some exception which will be produced only in IE.

Comment: @Oleg: thanks I found error there JSON is not defined. Can you please create answer so that I can mark it tick

Comment: You are welcome! I posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but the callback `loadComplete` do called in all web browsers in generally. It could be that an exception will be thrown during processing of some data in specific browser.

If you want to investigate the problem yourself I would recommend you to start the code in Developer Tools of IE (press <kbd>F12</kbd> to start) and then starting debugging in the "Script" tab. I suppose you'll get some exception which will be produced only in IE7.